# Grouping the checked check box row values using jQuery in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I need help in grouping the checked check box row values using jQuery in jsp page

In my jsp page I have brand name,product name(check box) and description(text box). On clicking the submit button the checked check  box row values i.e the Brand Name,Product Name and Description for all the checked ProductName checkboxes should be grouped together using a jQuery function and should be passed to the servlet for the database insertion.

Help me in grouping the checked check box row values and passing those values to the servlet.

I have tried using jQuery function but nothing is printed in my browser console.

This is my code.

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $('#btn').live('click', function() {
            var checkedRows = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
                checkedRows.push(
                  $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
                      return $(this).html();
                  }).get()
                ); 
             });        
            console.log( checkedRows );

        });
    </script>
```

**JSP Page**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
        <%@page import="web.Products"%>
        <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
        <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $('#btn').live('click', function() {
            var checkedRows = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
                checkedRows.push(
                  $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
                      return $(this).html();
                  }).get()
                ); 
             });        
            console.log( checkedRows );

        });
    </script>

    </head>
  <body>
         <form name="sform" method="post" action="Save_Products"> 
          <table style="width:40%">
              <tr> <th> Brand Name</th>
                  <th> Product Name</th>
                  <th> Description</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td><%
      List<Products> pdts = (List<Products>) request.getAttribute("productlist");
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
      out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"brand_name\" value=\""  + prod.getBrandname() + "\">");
          out.println("<br/>"+prod.getBrandname());

            } %> </td>
           <td><%
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
           out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prod\" checked=\"checked\" value=\""  + prod.getProductname() + "\">"  + prod.getProductname()+"<br>");
            } } %> </td>
           <td><%
           if(pdts!=null){
           for(Products prod: pdts){
            out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" style=\"width:50px; height:22px\" value=\""+prod.getDesc()+"\"/><br/>");
        } 
       }  
       } %> </td>  
       </tr>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center">  <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/> </td></tr> 

          </table>
             </form>
       </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Add this html from console can't figure out how many input are there.

Comment: Console is not needed for me. I need to group the checked check box rows and need to pass those values to my servlet page.So please help me in doing this.